# How do I transfer my entire itunes library (retaining the original music playlists) from my iPad iOS 5.1

Tags: itunes, ipad, macbook-pro

How do I transfer my entire itunes library (including the specific music playlists) from my original iPad iOS 5.1  via wifi to my new Macbook air with Yosemite?

The bulk of my music library is CD's that I have imported manually.

I have authorized both computers in the iTunes account tab.

I tried hooking my iPad, via it's USB cord, to the Macbook Air's USB port.  The iPad does pop up in iTunes, but I am not sure what to do next to permanently import all of the iPad's music, ibooks, movies etc. into the iTunes on my Macbook air.

Answer (score 1):

You don't move your Music from the iPad to the new computer, you copy your entire iTunes library from your old computer to your new computer and then re-sync your iPad to the new computer.

Here are the Apple instructions:
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4527

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try using the Home Sharing.

iTunes: Setting up Home Sharing on your computer

Home Sharing in iTunes lets you share and transfer content between multiple iTunes libraries on your home network....[read on here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4620).

and this article might be helpful.

[How to move your iTunes library to a new computer](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4527)

HT4527

Answer (score 0):

If you dare to spend a small amount of money, try http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/.
I am totally happy with that, I even can backup apps and their respective settings.
And I use it to sync my playlists and library from home to work by

I am really in love with that tool... :)